# Is there a way to blacklist a ethereum token

Tags: ethereum

Is there anyway to blacklist a erc20 token in an application ? Does each token have an unique identifier ? I assume the public key would be different after it has been transferred.

Comment: ERC20 is intended to be used for [fungible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fungibility) tokens. For a non-fungible token standard take a look at [ERC721](https://github.com/ethereum/eips/issues/721)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there anyway to blacklist a erc20 token in an application?

It depends on what kind of application. If you have an off chain application, you could blacklist it as part of your interface/backend systems, but if you rely on transactions signed by end users, they can always just send a transaction with the same effect as what your system would generate, but directly to a token contract.

If you have an app backed by a smart contract, you can block a token at a contract level, which will be effectively impossible to circumvent.

> Does each token have an unique identifier ?

Each token has a unique contract address, which will not change. Technically, a token could be made that allows contracts to be replaced, but it is rare, and would be easy enough to manually update your systems for.